# How to evaluate "any" condition against a nested list in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

| Child | Parent | Roots |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | [1,3,4] |
| 2 | 3 | [1,3,4] |
| 2 | 4 | [1,3,4] |
| 5 | 2 | [1,3,4] |
| 6 | 5 | [1,3,4] |

The first 2 fields represent a parent child relationship while the roots field represent the root parents for each row and is stored as a `list` due to the possibility of there being several.

I am trying to create a new field that would indicate whether the parent ID is one of the root parent like so:

| Child | Parent | Roots | RootParent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | [1,3,4] | True |
| 2 | 3 | [1,3,4] | True |
| 2 | 4 | [1,3,4] | True |
| 5 | 2 | [1,3,4] | False |
| 6 | 5 | [1,3,4] | False |

However, I am not sure how to apply the "any" logic correctly through the list comprehension, here are 2 methods I have tried thus far:

1. Method 1:

   ```
   dummy = []

   for row in x.itertuples():
       child, roots= row[1], row[3]
       for i in roots:
           if any(child==i):
               test = True
               dummy.append(test)
           else:
               test = False
               dummy.append(test)

   x['rootparent'] = dummy
   ```
2. Method 2:

   ```
   def test1 (a,b):
       for i in a:
           if b==i:
               return True
           else:
               return False
   dummy = []

   for row in x.itertuples():
       child, root = row[1], row[3]
       dummy.append(any(test1(root ,child)))

   x['rootparent'] = dummy
   ```

Is there any way to evaluate if the parent is within the root list for each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest way to reach your goal would be to use `.apply()`.

```py
df["RootParent"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["parent"] in row["root"], axis=1)
```

The with `axis=1` the lambda function receives the rows of the df. The `lambda` returns True if the `parent` is in the `root`list else it returns False.

Answer (score 1):

Another option via [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) + [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html#pandas-series-eq) + [`Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html#pandas-series-any) on level=0:

```
df['RootParent'] = df['Roots'].explode().eq(df['Parent']).any(level=0)
```

```
   Child  Parent      Roots  RootParent
0      2       1  [1, 3, 4]        True
1      2       3  [1, 3, 4]        True
2      2       4  [1, 3, 4]        True
3      5       2  [1, 3, 4]       False
4      6       5  [1, 3, 4]       False
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Child': [2, 2, 2, 5, 6],
    'Parent': [1, 3, 4, 2, 5],
    'Roots': [[1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4]]
})

df['RootParent'] = df['Roots'].explode().eq(df['Parent']).any(level=0)
print(df)
```